# JSON return format cordys BOP

Tags: json, xml, web-services, cordys-opentext

I'm using Cordys BOP and I have a REST web service that returns JSON format.  I have a test service that I use, that returns XML and this works fine so I know that my HTTP connector works right.  When I try to test my JSON service using the Test Web Service Operation UI, I get an error that says `Invalid XML response`.

How do I tell Cordys to expect a JSON response instead of an XML?

Is there a way to somehow wrap a JSON in XML through Cordys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to change the header:

```
 Content-type: application/json
```